# Split a pandas dataframe in multiple csv files keeping groups together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a 1M lines dataframe which consists of the following:
I do not really know the list of keys specifically so I cannot say, filter after Key ABCDE.

Key;Value

```
A;1
A;2
B;3
B;4
B;5
C;6
C;7
D;8
```

I would like to split this one into 3 dataframes keeping the groups together
So the result should be

```
A;1
A;2

B;3
B;4
B;5
C;6
C;7

D;8
```

So I would like to split it but it needs to keep the groups together,
you cannot do this for example

```
A;1
A;2
B;3

B;4
B;5
C;6

C;7
D;8
```

So I would like to split it after a group is finished.

I tried a bit with the pandas groupby function but no really sure how to do the split when you have all the groups together.

The split can be quite random eg. every 1K lines It does not really matter its more that the groups need to be together.

Comment: too many `So I want` :D

Comment: apoligies, I made a bit softer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, using groupby for example. Here's one way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"key":["A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D"],
                   "value":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

df.loc[df["key"] == "A", :].to_csv("filename_A.csv")
df.loc[(df["key"] == "B") | (df["key"] == "C"), :].to_csv("filename_BC.csv")
df.loc[df["key"] == "D", :].to_csv("filename_D.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks but not directly what I was after. Thing is that I have millions of lines so I do not know the keys, so I cannot smartly filter on them like you show. So I would like to split it but always split it after a group is finished

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) for split by groups and them select values in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
for i, key in enumerate(np.array_split(df['Key'].unique(), N)):
    print (key)
    df[df['Key'].isin(key)].to_csv(f'file{i}.csv', index=False)
```